# Implementing Q with Strongloop Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, loopbackjs

Q is a ["supporting module" of loopback](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/NODE/Supporting+module+reference).  I'm not totally sure what that means, but I'm assuming that it at least means that is possible to use Q with loopback's Persistent Model functions, like `find()` or `findOne()`. I'd like to know how to properly setup something like the following:

```
app.models.Question.findOne({
    where: {name: "My Question"}
}, function (err, result) {
    throw err if err
}).then(function () {
    console.log("success")
})
```

I have installed Q in my project's directory using NPM, but so far as I can tell, `app.models.Question.findOne()` is still returning undefined, rather than a usable Q promise.

According to the [loopback docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/NODE/Supporting+module+reference), using Q,

> If a function cannot return a value or throw an exception without
>   blocking, it can return a promise instead.

What do I need to do to get loopback to return a promise in this situation?

Comment: They seem to only use it internally if at all, but don't return promises from their methods.

Comment: Well what use is that? Seems like maybe a feature that would be useful to implement.

Comment: Then file a bug against them :-)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug that it doesn't use promises. ;) That said, could try [Q's `denodeify()` method](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfbindnodefunc-args) (although I'm honestly not sure if that would work).

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for promises are coming into core see: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/418

Answer (score 2):

LoopBack queries do not return promises at this point in time. Please post a feature request in the LoopBack repository to remind us (after reading https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/wiki/Issues of course). However, I do believe ES6 promises are on the roadmap.

That said, you can create your own promise and return that instead:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
app.models.Question.findOne({
  where: {
    name: 'My Question'
  }
}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) return deferred.reject(err);
  deferred.resolve(result);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

**NOTE** I haven't tested this, but it should be something along those lines. See https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds for more info.

Answer (score 1):

After a little more experimentation, I wound up implementing a variant of @superkhau's approach. (Pardon the coffee script).

```
app.wrapper = (model, fn, args)->
    deferred = Q.defer()
    args.push((err, result)->
        throw err if err
        deferred.resolve(result)
    )
    app.models[model][fn].apply(app.models[model], args)
    return deferred.promise
```

With that module in the bootscript, you can call the wrapper on any existing loopback model's method like so:

```
app.wrapper("Question", "findOne", [{
    where: {
        name: {'My Question'}
    }
}]).then((question)->
    console.log("Success!")
    console.log(question)
)
```

Note that the wrapper takes three arguments - the model name, the function name and an array of arguments. The arguments array should be an array of the arguments that the function would take if called normally.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a huge fan of the [`Q.ninvoke`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qninvokeobject-methodname-args) method of the popular [Q promise library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q), which it turns out has a method signature similar to @Morslamina's solution, but without the *having-to-write-it-myself* part. Which is nice, if you're a lazy coder like me.

```
loopback = require 'loopback'
q = require('q').ninvoke

app = module.exports = loopback()

app.get '/apples/:id', (res, req) ->
  q(app.models.Apple, 'findById', req.params.id).done (apple) ->
    res.render 'apple', apple: apple
```

It's not a bad way to get by until promises officially land in Loopback.